# Create single copy of functions for different instances of controller for an isolated scope directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say, I have a custom directive with isolated scope. Something like this:

```
mainApp.directive('student', function() {

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="displayName()">Student: <b>{{student.name}}</b> , Roll No: <b>{{student.rollno}}</b></div><br/>',
        scope: {
            student : "=name"
        },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){

      $scope.displayName = function(){
        console.log($scope.student.name);
      }

    }] 
    }   

});
```

Since scope is isolated, I am assuming it will instantiate a new controller with fresh `$scope` everytime I use the directive. If I create 10 instances of the directive, I will get 10 different scopes and each will have a different copy of `$scope.displayName()` function. This will consume unnecessary memory space. Is there a way in which we can have only a single copy of `$scope.displayName` instead in Angular? I am trying to do something like this:

```
Student.prototype.displayName = function(){
  console.log(this.student.name);
}

function Student(){
  this.student;
}
```

Have a single copy of functions, have separate copies of state variables. Refer this [pen](http://codepen.io/pix-el/pen/QvbBqv) for a sample. Although this is a simple example, the actual scenario is a bit complex.

Comment: you can pass displayName: '&' for function reuse.

Comment: @ABOS Will that create a single copy?

Comment: This does not make any sence - DOM nodes take much more memory.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yes, this example is just vague. Actual application has multiple functions with thousands of instances. I guess what ABOS says makes sense, I can pass in something from parent scope which will be only single copy. Just got too confused I guess.

Comment: use a service for re-usable function calls.  you can inject the service into any directive controller that needs it, and still only have one copy of the actual function in the service.

Comment: @Claies true, but in this case the function is attached to $scope, which means it can be attached to the view.

Comment: you can attach service functions to `$scope`.  functions are objects and are copied *byRef*, so `$scope.someService = service.someService` will create a singular reference copy usable in the HTML.

Comment: @Claies Makes sense.

Comment: This is one of reasons why controllerAs and bindToController are there - to allow to use constructor function instances instead of $scope, for prototypal inheritance in particular.